# What Is the Proper Project Configuration for the N Developer Preview?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

The docs claim a `build.gradle` like this works:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
  buildToolsVersion 24.0.0
  ...

  defaultConfig {
     minSdkVersion 'N'
     targetSdkVersion 'N'
     ...
  }
  ...
}
```

That gives me `failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0`, when using `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'` for the Android Plugin for Gradle and Gradle 2.5.

If I look in `build-tools/` in my Android SDK installation, I see `24.0.0-preview`, not `24.0.0`. However, if I switch my `build.gradle` to use `buildToolsVersion "24.0.0-preview"`, I get `Invalid revision: 24.0.0-preview`.

So, what combination of `build.gradle` values works to build a project to compile against the N Developer Preview SDK?

Comment: is your emulator running with N images ? Mine crashes at start up

Comment: I have the x86 emulator working (I haven't tried the x86_64 one), though I am doing more of my testing on hardware.

Comment: Why anyone would go for `Android N` as google have already said that its not a stable version until unless `Android N beta` released.

Comment: @Clairvoyant: Testing your apps on developer previews is fairly important. For example, your app might behave poorly as the user resizes the window using N's multi-window feature. Or, there may be specific things in the new version that you want to start developing now, so that once N ships in final form, you are ready to deploy an updated app (e.g., scoped directory access to give you better options for removable storage). If you want to wait for a later developer preview, that's your call.

Comment: But the thing is your OS might not work properly and you would think that your code or configuration is not correct. `Beta` version would give stability to your OS. `Preview` version is mainly for testing of device for New OS.

Comment: @ [this link](http://developer.android.com/preview/overview.html) u can see its an alpha version and rest preview version would be beta versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [one of the sample apps](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MultiWindowPlayground/blob/master/Application/build.gradle), I am now using:

- Gradle 2.10
- `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1'` for the Android Plugin for Gradle (goes in your top-level `build.gradle` file)
- `buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc1"`

This seems to be holding up, including with Android Studio 1.5.1.

**UPDATE**: Now that N Developer Preview 4 has been released, we can start using `24` in place of `"N"` and `"android-N"`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 24
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe issue occurred because of using `buildToolsVersion 24.0.0`.

According to [official set up guide](http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html), use:

```
  compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
  buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc1'

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 'N'
    targetSdkVersion 'N'
    ...
  }
```

Note that `minSdkVersion` other than 'N' works as well, but you'll have to use 'N' device to run your app anyways.

**Gradle 2.4** works for me. Also you don't have to use **'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1'** as it is mentioned in preview [samples](http://developer.android.com/preview/samples.html).
Using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'` works as well.

```
 dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
     ...
 }
```

**Don't forget to get the Java 8 JDK and JRE**. It is required to make it work on 'N', but you can set `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7` and `targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7` if not using Java 8 features.

> Note: Using the new Java 8 language features is not a requirement for developing apps that target the Android N platform. If you don't want to write code with Java 8 language features, you can keep your project's source and target compatibility values set to Java 7, but you still must compile with JDK 8 to build against the Android N platform.

Check [Java 8 Language Features](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to be rolling pretty well with this config on a new project with a PixelC:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc4'

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 'N'
        targetSdkVersion 'N'

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ActiveNotifications) you have to use

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.multiwindowplayground"
        minSdkVersion 'N'
        targetSdkVersion 'N'
  ....

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

- Android Studio 2.1 Preview
- Use gradle-2.10-all.zip
- `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1` for the Android Plugin
  for Gradle (goes in your top-level **build.gradle** file)
- buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc1"
- Select N: Android API 23, N Preview (Preview).
  Its working for me.

Comment: You do not need Android Studio 2.1. Also, [there does not appear to be a `2.1.0-alpha9` edition of the Android Plugin for Gradle](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view),at least at this time.

Comment: @CommonsWare You need Android Studio 2.1 to run N. It is clearly written in this link https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html

Comment: @VivekMishra: I am sitting here, with Android Studio 1.5.1, and I am perfectly capable of running Android N projects on an Android N device, given the project configuration from my answer. Android Studio 2.1 is needed for Java 8 support, should you choose to use that.

Comment: @CommonsWare Android Studio2.1 is for JDK 8. if you want to use JDK 7 then Android studio 1.5 + version you can use right. I have JDK 8  with android Studio 2.1 it works

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can not put minSdkVersionless than "N".
if you put a smaller version, or receive error, or go only +23 devices.

Comment: Thats not true. I have 8 as min SDK: 
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 'N'

Comment: I can make 17 but when I try to install the emulator receive error . 23+ only say . then it may be an error of windows .

Comment: that's not quite right. Basically you can use any version for minSdkVersion, but you will still need an "N" device to run the app.