# Failed to find target with hash string 'android-24'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-manager, android-7.0-nougat

[image]

I am getting this error after changing all the Google libraries to 24.0.0 and changing the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 24.
As you can see in the attached images I installed all Android N packages, but there only stands: "Partially installed".
How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no `targetSdkVersion` of 24, nor is there `compileSdkVersion` of 24, at this time. Those will be valid values (presumably) when the next version of Android ships.

For the N Developer Preview, based on [my work over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923621/what-is-the-proper-project-configuration-for-the-n-developer-preview), use:

- `compileSdkVersion 'android-N'`
- `buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc1'`
- `targetSdkVersion 'N'`

You also need Gradle 2.10 or higher (see your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file or your standalone Gradle installation) and `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1'` (see the top-level `build.gradle` file).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Could you please also add the link to the blog entry or where this information is provided?

Comment: @DropArt: I do not know what "blog entry" you are referring to. If you are referring to official Android documentation, I am not a Google engineer and cannot modify the documentation. I have tried for *years* to get them to fix documentation bugs with limited success.

Comment: @CommonsWare You misunderstood me. I meant from where you have this information?

Comment: @DropArt: A combination of [this bit of documentation](http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html), [this sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MultiWindowPlayground), and my own experimentation.

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me:
1. Manual install missing platforms in SDK Manager 
2. RESTART Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me:

- Updated Android Studio to the latest
- Restart Android Studio
- AS provides options to install missing platform plugins
- Click and update.

Answer (score 0):

open android studio as Run as administrator. It automatically installs missed sdks and all.